# Bootstrap 4 - image as overlay and mask

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 I'm trying to achieve an overlay effect with .png image which is also masking a part of bottom area of first section.

The height of .png image is 130px and it also should remain unscaled on mobile devices.

I've tried to use `::after` pseudoelements with content as background image on first section, but this gives me a unwanted bottom margin.

See my example here: https://codepen.io/michalwyrwa/pen/EGbxXb

Is there a better way to do it?

CSS:

```
body {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

.welcome .col {
    background-color: #3498db;
    height: 50vh;
}

.welcome::after {
    content: url(https://files.tinypic.pl/i/00976/nb1abpgxj5x3.png);
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.features .col {
    background-color: #6ab04c;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="welcome">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p class="my-3">Welcome text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="features">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p class="my-3">Features</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the root cause of your problem but I have the solution for you.

```
.welcome::after {
content: url(https://files.tinypic.pl/i/00976/nb1abpgxj5x3.png);
display: block;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: -6px;
}
```